# How to create Rails3 forms for embedded Mongoid models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How to create form for new User model with embedded Phone model?
I've found solution for creating form to add Phone for existing User but how to do that at the same time i create new User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a nested form

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Name:" %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :phone do |p| %>        
    <%= p.label :number, "Phone Number" %> <br />
    <%= p.text_field :number %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't forget to build an empty phone object in your controller: `@user.phone.build`

Comment: To get the values to display in an edit field (rails  3.2) I had to do <%= f.fields_for @user.phone do |p| %> rather than simply using the symbol.  Not sure if that's specific to my application setup or a common problem....

Comment: can you use autobuild: true in the model relation to avoid this?